# NgxLocalStorage Doesn't Retrieve Value

Tags: visual-studio, angular, local-storage, visual-studio-2017

I'm learning how to use the Visual Studio 2017 SPA Template for Angular 2.

For this exercise I would just like my HomeComponent to display the name of the logged on user stored in local storage (NgxLocalStorage) after logging in on my AppLoginComponent. https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-localstorage

I've researched this issue and I believe I'm going down the right track but for some reason my HomeComponent doesn't see the key/value pair in localStorage.  However, I can see it in Chrome's Developer Tools after I set it in login().

NgxLocalStorage has a method called get, not getItem but it appears to work the same way as getItem.  Unfortunately it's not retrieving my value.

I'm pretty new to Angular 2, I'm sure I'm just missing something somewhere, please help.

I have imported NgxLocalStorageModule into NgModule in app.module.shared:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NgxLocalStorageModule } from 'ngx-localstorage';

import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component';
import { NavMenuComponent } from './components/navmenu/navmenu.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { AppLoginComponent } from './components/applogin/applogin.component';
import { FacebookService, FacebookModule } from 'ngx-facebook/dist/esm/index';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        NavMenuComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        AppLoginComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        HttpModule,
        FormsModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'applogin', component: AppLoginComponent },
            { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
        ]),
        FacebookModule.forRoot(),
        NgxLocalStorageModule.forRoot()
    ],
    providers: [FacebookService, NgxLocalStorageModule]
})
export class AppModuleShared {
}
```

In my HomeComponent I have:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { LocalStorageService } from 'ngx-localstorage';

@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html'
})
export class HomeComponent {
    currentUser: string;

    constructor(private localStorage: LocalStorageService) {
        this.currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.get('currentUser') || '');
    }
}
```

In AppLoginComponent I have:

```
import { Component, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { FacebookService, InitParams, LoginResponse } from 'ngx-facebook/dist/esm/index';

import { LocalStorageService } from 'ngx-localstorage';

@Component({
    selector: 'applogin',
    templateUrl: './applogin.component.html'
})
export class AppLoginComponent {

    public loggedIn = false;
    name = "";

    constructor(private _ngZone: NgZone, private fb: FacebookService, localStorage: LocalStorageService) {

        let initParams: InitParams = {
            appId: '123456789',
            xfbml: true,
            version: 'v2.8'
        };

        fb.init(initParams);
    }

    login() {
        var self = this;
        this.fb.login()
            .then((res: LoginResponse) => {
                if (res.authResponse) {
                    this.fb.api('/me')
                            .then((res: any) => {
                                self._ngZone.run(() => {
                                self.name = res.name;
                                self.loggedIn = true;
                                localStorage.setItem('currentUser', res.name);
                        });
                    });
                } else {
                    alert('Not authorized.');
                }
            })
            .catch();
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to call setItem() and get() in one method, do make sure localStorage works? Maybe the two components get not the same instance of the service.

Comment: This worked, now how do I access the same storage across the app, for example my HomeComponent?

Comment: In `app.module.ts` you registered the `NgxLocalStorageModule` provider. This should make the service a singleton. Save the `localStorage` constructor parameter in a member variable of the component and access it with `this.localStorage`.

Comment: @zgue just need a little more information, please be more detailed, which constructor?  The HomeComponent constructor?

Comment: Make `localStorage` also a member of `AppLoginComponent ` and access it with `this.localStorage`. This way it has to be the injected service.

Comment: I'm not understanding, can you show me what my HomeComponent should look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have created [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/xI9YaxiLkVfzCcPEi8vT?p=preview) where everything works. You press login button it will navigate to different component and show user in console the only difference from your code i used

```
this.localStorage.set('item', item);
and this.localStorage.get('item');
```

also in your code

```
this.fb.api('/me')
                        .then((res: any) => {
                            self._ngZone.run(() => {
                            self.name = res.name;
                            self.loggedIn = true;
                            localStorage.setItem('currentUser', res.name);
                    });
                });
```

you can't use like this services outside constructor and don't use self you need to add 'this'. and in you constructor prefix localStorage with private
and do initialization better in OnInit hook.

```
    import { Component, NgZone, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FacebookService, InitParams, LoginResponse } from 'ngx-facebook/dist/esm/index';

import { LocalStorageService } from 'ngx-localstorage';

@Component({
    selector: 'applogin',
    templateUrl: './applogin.component.html'
})
export class AppLoginComponent implements OnInit  {

    public loggedIn = false;
    name = "";

    constructor(private _ngZone: NgZone, private fb: FacebookService, private localStorage: LocalStorageService) {


    }

   ngOnInit() {
     let initParams: InitParams = {
            appId: '123456789',
            xfbml: true,
            version: 'v2.8'
        };

        fb.init(initParams);
   }

    login() {
        this.fb.login()
            .then((res: LoginResponse) => {
                if (res.authResponse) {
                    this.fb.api('/me')
                            .then((res: any) => {
                                this._ngZone.run(() => {
                                this.name = res.name;
                                this.loggedIn = true;
                                this.localStorage.set('currentUser', res.name);
                        });
                    });
                } else {
                    alert('Not authorized.');
                }
            })
            .catch();
    }
```

and in app.module.shared.ts remove this line

```
 providers: [FacebookService, NgxLocalStorageModule]
```

cause forRoot is importing them already. should be like this

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        NavMenuComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        AppLoginComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        HttpModule,
        FormsModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'applogin', component: AppLoginComponent },
            { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
        ]),
        FacebookModule.forRoot(),
        NgxLocalStorageModule.forRoot()
    ]
})
export class AppModuleShared {
}
```

and the last

```
import { FacebookService, FacebookModule } from 'ngx-facebook/dist/esm/index';
```

try to use import without dist

```
import { FacebookModule } from 'ngx-facebook';
```

Comment: OK I've run this in Plunker and looked over the code but I don't really see how this answers my question.

Comment: You wanted to store user name in LocalStorage then retrieve it and show In template isn't it??

Comment: Yes, but your Plunker example is not displaying the user name anywhere.

Comment: sorry about that :-) https://plnkr.co/edit/xI9YaxiLkVfzCcPEi8vT?p=preview

Comment: it was displaying in console log forgot to show in UI. User works is name. Press login and you will see.

Comment: Yes, looks good, just need to apply it to my code tonight, then I'll award the bounty to you.

Comment: Good Luck :-) Thank You. if You can upvote please want to be in best 20 this month on angular.

Comment: Thank You even made to 14 place!

Answer (score 2):

The input has to be a string. You can put in some mock data like

```
localStorage.setItem('currentUser', 'TrevorBrooks');
```

and retrieve it via get to be sure there is a item saved. And check what data type you are sending. Is it a user object or is it just the name?

Greetings

Comment: sorry but I already know this.  this isn't the problem I'm having.

Answer (score 2):

You should use **NgOnInit**, is the best approach for your problem than using the constructor since the constructor is for initialization, dependency injection among others.. so, what could be happening is that the data is not yet available by the time you request it. Besides in the npmjs.com page they clearly add an example using ngOnInit so i guess they saw this issue coming.

In your components, do `import { .., OnInit, .. } from '@angular/core';`

`
so you'd have something like:

```
import { Component, NgZone, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
```

and in your component export class:

```
export class AppLoginComponent implements OnInit{

ngOnInit() {
   //write your code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1.Make sure you have been installed the local storage module from npm

```
npm install --save angular2-localstorage
```

2.Import the WebStorageModule in your app module:

```
import {Component} from "angular2/core";
import {WebStorageModule, LocalStorageService} from "angular2-localstorage";

@NgModule({
    import: [WebStorageModule]
@Component({
    providers: [LocalStorageService]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

2.Use the LocalStorage decorator

import {LocalStorage, SessionStorage} from "angular2-localstorage/WebStorage";

```
class MySuperComponent {
    @LocalStorage() public lastSearchQuery:Object = {};
    @LocalStorage('differentLocalStorageKey') public lastSearchQuery:Object = {};
}
```

## Example

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-login',
    template: `
<form>
    <div>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="username" placeholder="Username" />
        <input type="password" [(ngModel)]="password" placeholder="Password" />
    </div>

    <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="rememberMe" /> Keep me logged in

    <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
    `
})
class AppLoginComponent {
    //here happens the magic. `username` is always restored from the localstorage when you reload the site
    @LocalStorage() public username:string = '';

    public password:string;

    //here happens the magic. `rememberMe` is always restored from the localstorage when you reload the site
    @LocalStorage() public rememberMe:boolean = false;
}
```

## View

```
@Component({
    selector: 'admin-menu',
    template: `
<div *ngFor="#menuItem of menuItems() | mapToIterable; #i = index">
    <h2 (click)="hiddenMenuItems[i] = !!!hiddenMenuItems[i]">
        {{i}}: {{category.label}}
    </h2>
    <div style="padding-left: 15px;" [hidden]="hiddenMenuItems[i]">
        <a href>Some sub menu item 1</a>
        <a href>Some sub menu item 2</a>
        <a href>Some sub menu item 3</a>
    </div>
</div>
    `
})
class AdminMenuComponent {
    public menuItems = [{title: 'Menu1'}, {title: 'Menu2'}, {title: 'Menu3'}];

    //here happens the magic. `hiddenMenuItems` is always restored from the localstorage when you reload the site
    @LocalStorage() public hiddenMenuItems:Array<boolean> = [];

    //here happens the magic. `profile` is always restored from the sessionStorage when you reload the site from the current tab/browser. This is perfect for more sensitive information that shouldn't stay once the user closes the browser.
    @SessionStorage() public profile:any = {};
}
```

For more Clarification refer this link [link](https://github.com/marcj/angular2-localstorage)